# How to penalize decision tree for misclassifying a certain class?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

You can simply copy/paste the code to run in your environment.

The scientific term I found for it is **Cost minimization** while the algorithm applies **accuracy maximization**. That is the algorithm aims to get the highest score in accuracy while I don't care about the accuracy, I care about not misclassifying a certain class.

I know the following uses the CART algorithm for decision trees, how can I change it to stress that misclassifying a False is more dangerous than misclassing a positive. I know the term is **Cost Minimization** but I am not sure how to apply it or what books to search for in.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class',axis = 1)


dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of two options:

**Increase the weight of Positive class**

[DecisionTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) has a parameter that let you change the default weights for each class. The default is the balanced one, which means, all the classes have weight = 1. To minimise false negatives, you could give greater weights for your positive class labelled data.

**Create your scoring function to minimise the false negatives**

The algorithm calculates probabilities for each class. If you have two class classification problem, then if the probabilities for one sample is >=0.5, then it is scored as 1, and if it is <0.5, it is scored as 0.

Those probabilities are returned with the trained model, and you can get them by `dt.predict_proba`. So instead of getting the scored label that your model returned, use the predicted probabilities to create your score function that will minimise the false negatives on the cost matrix.

Comment: the first solution you mentioned is the closest to me, if no one else answers in a while, I will mark your answer as the solution. Yes, increaasing the weight of one class is one approach, but how can we penalize the algorithm for misclassifying a certain class?